# php glob function in a php include for multiple web directories

Tags: php, html, include, glob

Long time reader, first time poster, and pretty inexperienced with php (I know enough to be dangerous to myself), so please be patient with my ignorance.

I have a relatively large, hand coded static website that makes usage of PHP includes for headers, sidebars, etc.  I want to pull the latest image from a directory and display it in one of the sidebars, but the directory's location relative to the current page constantly changes.

```
<?php
$pictures = glob("ktracy-includes/recent-image/*.*"); 
$no_pictures = count($pictures)-1;  
$limit = $no_pictures-0;
for( $i = $no_pictures; $i >= $limit; $i--){
echo "<img width=300px src=\"".$pictures[$i]."\" />\n"; 
}  
?>
```

This works fine on `ktracy.com/index.php,` but it breaks on `ktracy.com/archives/index.php` and `ktracy.com/archives/2001/index.php`

I tried this, but it failed everywhere:

```
<?php
$pictures = glob("https://ktracy.com/ktracy-includes/recent-image/*.*"); 
$no_pictures = count($pictures)-1;  
$limit = $no_pictures-0;
for( $i = $no_pictures; $i >= $limit; $i--){
echo "<img width=300px src=\"".$pictures[$i]."\" />\n"; 
}  
?>
```

---

**UPDATE**

I think this is a response to a couple of responses:

Per Ken Lee's suggestion, I tried the following

```
$pictures =glob($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/ktracy-includes/recent-image/*.*");
```

This returned the following HTML; which includes my file structure.

```
<img width="300px" src="/home3/*redacted*/public_html/ktracy-includes/recent-image/September 28, 2022 at 1011PM.jpg">
```

I guess I need a way to convert `/home3/*redacted*/public_html/` to `https://www.ktracy.com`. If Honk der Hase is correct that glob can't be used for this, is there something else I should try?

Comment: `glob()` only works on a file system...

Comment: Use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` as your path prefix.

Comment: The question is really, what is the folder structure under these other 2 folders?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: change to `$pictures =glob($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/ktracy-includes/recent-image/*.*");` and re-try

Comment: Code changed.  It outputs the following:  `<img width="300px" src="/home3/*redacted*/public_html/ktracy-includes/recent-image/September 28, 2022 at 1011PM.jpg">`  The image is still broken, but at least now it's finding the file name.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for helping me understand the problem.  I ended up using an iframe to display the code that worked in a parent directory mentioned above.  The iframe is linked to the hard URL of that php file so the directory won't change.  I'm still not sure there wasn't another way to do this, but it works well enough and since my image height won't change, I can use an iframe without any major problems.

Thanks again!